# Optional fields in classes

Tags: typescript

```js
class Person { 
  name?: String 
}
```

Here, the signature for name is equivalent to `name: string | undefined`, as opposed to null.

Something inside me is revolting against the notion that a class member would be undefined, because that's the way I learned JS: Undefined is for the framework only, and it represents the absence of a field, versus the absence of a value (which is indicated by null)

To make things worse, with strict null checks enabled, since **null !== undefined**, if you wanted to clear out a field, you'd have to do this.name = undefined, or delete this.name, both of which also raise alarm bells for me.

So then I see people doing this: `name?: string | null`. That solves the awkwardness of nulling the field, but now, for no real reason, you have "string | undefined | null"

It seems that it would be more correct to just do "string | null", which solves most things.

It seems that the TS team has internally decided to use only undefined, although they are very clear that their decision is not prescriptive for the community (after all, then why add null to the language?)

For a long time it was considered dangerous to use `undefined` explicitly in code, because it was a value, not a keyword, and could be implemented differently (or mutable) on different implementations. For this reason, it was also taboo to do `if(x === undefined)`, in favor of a `typeof` check. **Is this no longer true?**

**Is it legitimate to define class members as optional?**

Comment: Seems like an opinion question to me... you can choose `name?: string` (not `String`, please) or `name: string | null = null` (initialize it to `null` please because it won't happen by itself); neither is necessarily better or worse.  `x === undefined` is usually safe; if you're concerned you can use `x === void 0`.  Not sure how any answer can be authoritative or canonical, though.

Comment: There are compelling arguments to use `undefined`. Crockford style ftw!

Comment: It's an opinion question in so far as anything about which the language is non-opinionated is a matter of opinion. However, I'm sure you'll agree that every language allows you to do things which are anti-patterns or are otherwise obscene. I'm trying to determine whether this is such a case

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript opted to use `undefined`. That doesn't mean you can't use `null` of course. But there is not a fine line to say when to use which.

TypeScript guide lines for **their codebase** suggests to always use `undefined` instead of `null`.

What you're trying to achieve is this:

```
class Person { 
  name: string | null = null;
}
```

Really nice article about Null vs Undefined at:
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/null-undefined.html

Comment: `name: string | null` doesn't initialize the property properly (should warn you in `--strict` mode).  Instead `name: string | null = null` should work.

Comment: Sure. Each has its place. I'm aware of the options. I'm trying to figure out if this is bad usage of the optional operator